# Why ASIHTTPRequest still ask for ssl even though I close it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

A connection failure occurred: SSL problem

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.trevesstudios.com/indexappyness1.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:year1 forKey:@"year"];
[request setPostValue:appy_level forKey:@"appy_level"];
[request setPostValue:reasons forKey:@"reasons"];
[request setPostValue:country forKey:@"country"];
[request setPostValue:city forKey:@"city"];
[request setPostValue:sex forKey:@"sex"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the error message you're seeing?

Comment: A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (Possible causes may include a bad/expired/self-signed certificate, clock set to wrong date) of course mate this is the full error message ive been getting.

Comment: If I try to view the URL you're posting to in Chrome or IE I get errors regarding SSL and the page not being displayed. Are you sure your site is working correctly?

Comment: Yet it works fine if I drop the `s` and just hit the `http`

Comment: well i am looking the site atm there is noting show in it if you want i can send the php code too this site is empty just take the post values and write them to database

Comment: What I mean is if I try to load `https://www.trevesstudios.com/indexappyness1.php` in Chrome, I get greeted with `Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.` However, if I drop the `s` and just hit `http://www.trevesstudios.com/indexappyness1.php` the blank page loads as expected without issue. This would suggest the error lies with your site and specifically the SSL certificate rather than with ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: ah how can i miss it thanks alot mate i was try to fix it like a day and i just miss it can't believe thanks alot

Comment: No worries, I'll pop an official answer below and then you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error may lie with your SSL certificate rather than with ASIHTTPRequest.

If I try to access https://www.trevesstudios.com/indexappyness1.php from Chrome or IE I get the following error

> Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.

however if I drop the secure connection and just try to access it using plain ol' HTTP the pages loads as normal without error.